# Metro apps make my mouse weird

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, modern-ui

I have 3 monitors connected and set up in the right order, but whenever I launch the Mail app (or any other W8 app) my mouse cannot cross the edge of the screen.

Now the weird part is that it actually can, but only when I move my mouse rather quickly. I tried closing the process, but that doesn't help. The only thing that makes it work normally again is a reboot. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I'd guess this was done deliberately to make it easier to hit active zones at the borders of the screen. This also explains why speed matters, because a fast movement might be taken to indicate that you want to go beyond the edge. The closing part on the other hand is weird.

Comment: This behavior is intentional.

Comment: It only did this within 10 pixels of the corners before, which was really nice. This is plain annoying and I'm not really sure it's intentional. From boot and until I start something that is not the desktop it doesn't require extra speed to cross the edge. But when I start one and even after I close it, this happens. I have had 3 monitors and 8.1 since it was released and this has never happened to me before.

Comment: Just to check about a different issue with multiple monitors, is the verticle resolution on all the monitors all the same?

Comment: @Psycogeek, yes, they are all 1920x1080 monitors of the same brand

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, this is actually a feature. I'm not sure why it hasn't happened before in the year's time I've been using 8.1. It's usually called sticky edges by users and can be disabled by updating the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` changing the DWORD `MouseMonitorEscapeSpeed` from 0 (enabled) to 1 (disabled), followed by a reboot.

Source: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/49401-sticky-edges-multi-monitors-enable-disable.html